# aligning memory in VirtualAlloc

Tags: winapi, virtual-memory

As an optimization for some code on Win64, I am reserving 4GB of address space and then commit some number of MB (e.g. 512MB) within that address space (which ultimately gives huge perf improvements from array bound check removal, but that is all beside the point). The code I have basically looks like this:

```
LPVOID address = VirtualAlloc(null, FOUR_GB, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_NOACCESS);
arrayAddress = VirtualAlloc(address, length, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
```

Someone on my team recently read a paper about large pages requiring less TLB lookups and having significant performance improvement in some scenarios, and this seemed like a prime candidate for trying that out.

However, what I'm reading makes me think that maybe this won't work. MSDN says that "the size and alignment must be a multiple of the large-page minimum". I can easily ensure that length is a multiple of large-page minimum, but how can I do this for alignment? If I could pass MEM_LARGE_PAGES flag to the reservation, I assume that would align it correctly. But I've read that you cannot call VirtualAlloc with MEM_RESERVE|MEM_LARGE_PAGES.

So my thought is that I can do what I'm doing now, but do VirtualAlloc with FOUR_GB+GetLargePageMinimum() during reservation and then align address to GetLargePageMinimum() when committing, but this doesn't feel right to me.

Does anyone know the correct way to go about it?

Comment: This is an edge case, it seems likely that Microsoft didn't anticipate anyone wanting to do this.  So while I don't know for sure, I suspect that your proposed algorithm is indeed the only way to do it.

Comment: As far as I'm aware the Glasgow Haskell Compiler runtime [reserves an 1+ TiB virtual memory region at the startup on 64-bit platforms and commits whenever needed](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/9706). Feel free to check out their implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using large (or huge) pages will significantly lower the TLB pressure and thus improve memory access performance. We use it to great benefits in our SCADA software. SQL Server does too.

[Large pages on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/large-page-support) are non-pageable, i.e. always locked in memory. Cannot be reserved, only fully committed. Locking pages is special privileged operation, and [SeLockMemoryPrivilege](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/lock-pages-in-memory) is not normally configured for any account on the machine, not even SYSTEM. Nevertheless it can be [added](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-the-lock-pages-in-memory-option-windows) and [enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/enabling-and-disabling-privileges-in-c--).

Then this will work:

```
VirtualAlloc (NULL, size, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT | MEM_LARGE_PAGES, PAGE_READWRITE);
```

You don't have to worry about huge (1GB) pages. Windows (1607+, Server 2016+) will, if possible, allocate one for you, when you request enough 2MB ones, and it is available.

You don't have to worry about alignment, you will get them aligned to 2MB (or 1GB).

But you can request both, 1GB pages and extra alignment, using [VirtualAlloc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc2) API available since Windows 10 version 1803 (RS4, build 17134) and Server 2019, like this:

```
MEM_ADDRESS_REQUIREMENTS requirement;
requirement.LowestStartingAddress = NULL;
requirement.HighestEndingAddress = NULL;
requirement.Alignment = 4 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024; // align to 4GB boundary

MEM_EXTENDED_PARAMETER xp[2];
xp[0].Type = MemExtendedParameterAddressRequirements;
xp[0].Pointer = &requirement;

xp[1].Type = MemExtendedParameterAttributeFlags;
xp[1].ULong64 = MEM_EXTENDED_PARAMETER_NONPAGED_HUGE; // 1GB pages required

VirtualAlloc2 (NULL, NULL, size, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE, xp, 2);
```